# Using mimekit.mimemessage to load eml files from hard disk how can I load only text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mimekit

This is how I'm using it today

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int counter = 0;
    MimekitallLoadedMessages = new List<MimeKit.MimeMessage>();
    MimeKit.MimeMessage loadedMessage = null;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(emailsDirectory);
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        string uid = seenUids[0];
        loadedMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(files[i].FullName);
        MimekitallLoadedMessages.Add(loadedMessage);
        downloaded.Add(seenUids[i]);
        counter += 1;
        int nProgress = counter * 100 / files.Length;
        backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(nProgress);
    }
}
```

The method Load just load the whole message.
But i wander if i can Load for exmaple on the subject of each message and teh add it to a listView for example so the user later will be able to select a specific email to load it's all content like the html or the whole body content.

So loading only the subject and make a list of all the emails in the listView will load the messages faster. I have like 6000 eml files on hard disk.

Loading all the files and add all the messages to the listView might take some time. Instead maybe loading/parsing only the text might be faster ?

Is it possible ? And logic ? Maybe when i download the messages first time i should create a text file with all the subjects of each email and then when running my program just to read the lines from the text file, each line is a subject ?

UPDATE

This is the dowork event now:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            MimeKit.HeaderList loaded = new MimeKit.HeaderList();
            int counter = 0;
            MimekitallLoadedMessages = new List<MimeKit.MimeMessage>();
            MimeKit.MimeMessage loadedMessage = null;
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(emailsDirectory);
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                string uid = seenUids[0];
                loaded = MimeKit.HeaderList.Load(files[i].FullName);
                var subject = loaded[MimeKit.HeaderId.Subject];
                downloaded.Add(seenUids[i]);
                counter += 1;
                int nProgress = counter * 100 / files.Length;
                backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(nProgress, subject);
            }
         }
```

And the progresschanged event how i'm updating the listView control:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbt1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            pbt1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            pbt1.Invalidate();
            if (e.UserState != null)
            {

                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
            {
                e.UserState.ToString()
            }));
            }
         }
```

Comment: So you just want to read the subject from these messages?

Comment: You right and your code idea Yacoub is good and fast the problem is updating the ui in the progresschanged event. I'm trying to add the subject as string items to a listView in real time but updating the listView make it all slow and not smooth.

Comment: I just eidted and updated my question with what i tried so far.

Comment: Are you using .NET >= 4.5?

Comment: The background worker is considered obsolete. You can use async/await to do what you are trying to do in a smaller number of lines.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the UI? Is it listview flickering? Try to add multiple items at once. E.g. call `ReportProgress` for each 10 or 20 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the headers only if you want via `HeaderList.Load`. This will be faster than parsing the whole message. Here is an example:

```
string filename = ...

var headerList = HeaderList.Load(filename);

var subject = headerList[HeaderId.Subject];
```